# using bash commands from sublime 2 IDE plugin?

Tags: bash, unix, plugins

is it possible that using the sublime 2 plugin API call to the operating system?

(using mac os / unix)

For example, say I have a script that I execute in bash like this

```
#!/bin/bash

perl -i -pe 's/[\t]{1,}\n/\n/g' ${TM_FILEPATH};
```

and wanted to call it from sublime using a plugin.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Did you check [Shell-Turtlestein](https://github.com/misfo/Shell-Turtlestein) or, you know, [terminal](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/terminal)? Also, AFAIK, [SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL/) supports Perl. If you need terminal in the Sublime window, you can use [SublimePTY](https://github.com/wuub/SublimePTY)